# Execute stored procedure with null values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure has been created in the database :

```
@se_code_melli varchar(10) = NULL,
@se_name nvarchar(30) = NULL,
@se_family nvarchar(30) = NULL,
@se_name_uni nvarchar(100) = NULL,
@se_name_reshte_tahsili nvarchar(50) = NULL
```

With the commands below, I want to run stored procedure from my C# program :

```
if (comboBox11.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    comboBox11.SelectedValue = DBNull.Value;
}

if (comboBox12.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    comboBox12.SelectedValue = DBNull.Value;
}

sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_code_melli",  Value = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox23.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)textBox23.Text)},
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_name",  Value = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox22.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)textBox22.Text)},
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_family",  Value = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox21.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)textBox21.Text)},
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_name_uni",  Value =comboBox11.SelectedValue},
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_name_reshte_tahsili",  Value =comboBox12.SelectedValue}
        };

using (SamenEntities dbContext = new SamenEntities())
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SamenEntities>("storedProcedureName", sqlParams).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

But I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@se_code_melli nvarchar(10),@se_name nvarchar(4000),@se_family ' expects the parameter '@se_name_uni', which was not supplied.'

I tried to solve the NULL problem, but I did not succeed.

Comment: Any reason why you don't replace `comboBox11.SelectedValue` with a DbNull instead of a null?

Comment: @vc74 , with two if condition, this does not happen?

Comment: Since your procedure has a default value (null) you could *not supply* the parameter at all if the value is null. If you do add the parameter to the command you can use DBNull.Value as others have said.

Comment: @solmazahamdi As detailed in Marc's post below, the parameter may not be sent if null which is not the case with DbNull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADO.NET has a *really really* odd feature: if a parameter has the value `null`, it *isn't sent*. This confuses *everyone*. Instead, you must manually avoid adding `null`, and add `DBNull.Value` instead.

Clearly your `comboBox11.SelectedValue = DBNull.Value;` attempt didn't work, so : set it at the ADO.NET level instead.

For example:

```
new SqlParameter {
    ParameterName = "@se_name_uni",
    Value = (object)comboBox11.SelectedValue ?? DBNull.Value
},
```

Alternatively, most ORM or micro-ORM tools will know to do this for you automatically.